# How to make the same name of the customer only once registered

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-account, register

[image: Customer repeat registration]

How to make the same name of the customer only once registered

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your question?

Comment: There's a lot of people who have the same name? I would agree with @MohitKumarArora, could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 5):

Many people have the same name so I would strongly advise against trying to block users!
If you believe your site is being targeted by bots I would suggest you implement Google Recaptcha on the register form

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by checking whether any customer with same name exist or not. You can check the existence of customer by using onblur attribute on name field. 
To check the existence use following code.

```
 $name = 'John Doe';   //Name of customer comes here
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('firstname',$name);

            if(count($customer)){
                    echo 'Customer already exist.';
}
```